# SQL Server: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'na' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Getting the above mentioned error in SQL.

I have tried below coding but nothing is working for me. Any suggestions??

```
cast(fieldvalue as nvarchar)
```

Comment: Very confusing... You say cast as nvarchar, but the error message says cast as int...

Comment: What is the value you're trying to convert? From what data type? To what data type?

Comment: i don't need to convert the value to any data type, The dataype of the filed is "Int ( 4 )" . when i am trying to pull the results of filedvalue it gives me the mentioned error. I had applied this cast as nvarchar in an attempt to solve the error

Comment: Show us the table definition(s), and the whole statement that returns an error, and the whole error message.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `(n)varchar` variables and parameters and values in conversion that you use

Comment: The problem is that you haven't posted your full query. That is not a query you've posted. Post the full query and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand exactly what do you want..but I think you want to cast from int to nvarchar in sql.

so do this for it :`CAST(fieldvalue as nvarchar(max))`

Comment: Thanks Vidhi. I have been inactive for few days. I will try you solution. Thanks for help